# Token use in message_notify

Tags: commerce

I am unable to get tokens to display in a  message I have created. I am looking to resend an order confirmation email.

I am using message_notify.

Standard tokens like site:name work fine but when I try commerce-order tokens the string is output not the token value

This is the callback function I have so far:

```
// Resend confirmation email
function commerce_cc_resend_confirmation_email($order){

 $variables = array(
    '@test' => 'this is a test',
    '@replace' => 'fsdfdsfdsf'
  );

  $message = message_create('commerce_resend_order_confirmation_email', $variables);
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('message', $message);

  message_notify_send_message($message, $variables);

  $output = "An order confirmation email has been sent. " ; 

  return $output; 

}
```